# linux : test for software RAID

Tags: linux, raid, software-raid

On a bunch of servers, I wish to automate the test for software RAID.

1. Is it a viable solution to check [/proc/mdstat](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Mdstat) ?
2. Does *Personalities* list any only if SOFTWARE RAID ?
3. If no software RAID, can I stop these daemons ? *mdmonitor mdadm mdmpd*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, and it's probably the quickest & easiest way if all you're interested in is `mdadm` software raid (and not `lvm` or `btrfs` etc) - but the raid device names are arbitrary (so you can't just assume they'll match `^md[0-9]+` - most will but they don't have to and the default/standard may change in future).

   BTW, here's a python `/proc/mdstat` parser: https://github.com/truveris/py-mdstat/ (this includes an `mdjson` tool to print `/proc/mdstat` in json format)

   This was just the first one I found with google, there are certain to be others for `perl`, `awk`, and other languages.

   And here's a very quick-and-dirty `awk` one-liner that detects if there are any raid devices (by assuming that if the second field of any input line after the first line is a colon `:`, then that indicates a raid device):

   `awk 'NR > 1 && $2 == ":" {found++}; END {exit !found}' /proc/mdstat`

   It exits with true (0) if one or more devices are found, false otherwise.
2. `Personalities` just lists the types of `mdadm` raid supported by the kernel.  It does **not** indicate that ANY of them are actively being used, just that the kernel has the requisite driver compiled in (or module loaded)
3. Sure, why not.  If they're not doing anything useful, there's no need to run them, or even have them installed.

Comment: Personalities : list is empty. Can we assume *no madm raid* so it is safe to stop the daemons ?

Comment: I feel unstable to test the output of /proc/mdstat ... parsing lines ... Is there any other way to get raw info about software raid ?

Comment: yes, if the Personalities list is empty, there can be no mdadm raid.  I should have thought of that myself.   the awk one-liner will return the same result, anyway - there are no arrays to be found.

Comment: and I forgot : if */proc/mdstat* doesn't exist ?

Comment: `if [ ! -e /proc/mdstat ] && ! awk '......' ; then do-something-to-stop-and-remove-mdam;  fi`